# Is there any JSON find operation available to use in PHP?

Tags: php, json, find

Is there any find function available to use with PHP?

I mean if I want to fetch all records whose category = 'red', is it possible?

e.g.

```
[{"id":1,"name":"a","colour":"red"},{"id":2,"name":"b","colour":"red"},{"id":3,"name":"c","colour":"green"},{"id":4,"name":"d","colour":"green"}]
```

now I want to retrieve all records whose **colour = red** , then can I perform this operation or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: Its a good option, but point is something like Xquery is available with XML----- I think json is growing and will incorporate such features afterwards

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = json_decode($str, true);
foreach ($arr as $row) {
    if ($row['colour'] == 'red') {
        echo $row['id'];
    }
}
```